# iOS application security: Which is the more secure option for storing license keys, Plist file OR an Objective-C file with "extern static" strings

Tags: ios, security

I am using few third party libraries for which I need to store the license keys somewhere globally (So that it's easy to update, when needed) inside the app.

As of now, I'm having a Plist file in Resources bundle which has all the license keys in Dictionary format. This is working fine as I expected because I can access Plist file from all the source files.

But, when it comes security, is this a good approach? I was just trying to rename the .IPA file to .zip and unzip the same. The entire Plist file becomes accessible to others.

So, I was thinking this might be a better approach to store the license keys in Objective-C source files using extern static (to make it globally available).

Can anyone please suggest me on this. Please let me know if I missed something.

Comment: Hardcoded strings would at least be a step better than the plist, since someone would have to reverse engineer the binary to get to them.

Comment: @Fonix does running strings not work on current binaries? I haven't tried it recently

Comment: @Wain by running strings do you mean just getting the string out of the running app with a memory dump or something? im sure this would still be a problem these days, which i forgot to mention

Comment: @Wain The binary is encrypted when you get it from the app store, so you do have to jump through a few hoops to run strings on it.

Answer (score 2):

Your 2 options are about the same, it would take an extra XX minutes to pull the keys out of the code if they were static strings. It does take a little more knowledge but most normal people wouldn't generally know how to unzip the app I guess...

A simple option is to keep the same storage, either way, but to store obfuscated keys and have a piece of code that you use to unpack and restore the keys.

There are also some libraries that you can use to store obfuscated keys and return the originals, but, as libraries become more popular it gets easier for people to guess what kind of obfuscation is used and therefore discover the truth... You're just trying to make it a bit more difficult and less obvious what your keys are and what they're for.

Comment: Also, what if I use SHA-1 encryption. I can store encrypted strings in the plist. Is that bad idea?

Comment: @RashmiRanjanmallick you will still have to store the encryption key somewhere, so you will be left with the same problem basically. but at least it wouldnt be plain text